# java Process.waitfor is a blocking call

Tags: java, process, event-handling, reactive-programming

I want to be able to kick off an external process from within the JVM and reach on its completion.

I could use the ProcessBuilder to create a Process and then do Process.waitFor() to wait for its completion. However, this a blocking call and simply wastes thread resources.

It would make better sense to do this via an event handler and reactive programming. One would think that the JVM could register some sort of a listener with the OS to listen for process completion events, and relay that back to the program.

Does such a mechanism/ API exist? Any alternatives or libraries that achieve this?

Comment: Yes; you would think that Java would be able to do this.  Unfortunately, however, Java doesn't really know what async means, so you're stuck.  Use C#. _</rant>_

Comment: Check http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling/

Comment: @SLaks, Java has another problem at hand - being portable. Perhaps that was the issue with this feature.

Comment: @soulseekah, Did understand the relationship between the article and my question. Were you suggesting that there is a way in the JVM to handle process termination signal from a different process ?

Comment: @vishr: I don't think so. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1393083/34397

Comment: This is an old question, but I have a new answer.  I have created an open source library that allows non-blocking I/O between java and your child processes.  The library provides an event-driven callback model.  It depends on the JNA library to use platform-specific native APIs, such as epoll on Linux, kqueue/kevent on MacOS X, or IO Completion Ports on Windows.

The project is called NuProcess and can be found here: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess

Answer (score 5):

Use the [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) library if you only need to support Windows, MacOS X, and Linux.  It provides non-blocking access to external processes using a callback model -- including I/O and program termination.  *Disclosure: I am the author of said library.*

Answer (score 3):

Spawn new thread that will wait for process completion:

```
    final Process process = ...;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // thread is interrupted, check process state
            }
            // signal main thread
        }
    }).start();
```

Or use Executors:

```
    Future<String> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            process.waitFor();
            return "OK";
        }
    });
```

Later allows you to check job status via Future API: `future.isDone()`, `future.cancel()`, ...

Comment: yes - but this is exactly what I want to avoid - wasting thread resources by invoking a blocking call. This thread could be doing something else worthwhile in the system thereby improving throughput.

Comment: i don't think blocked threads consume any resources, the only overhead is thread itself. if your application spawns a lot of processes, then this solution is not for you obviously. and even in this case you can use fixed thread pools.

Answer (score 1):

> One would think that the JVM could register some sort of a listener with the OS to listen for process completion events, and relay that back to the program.

Only if all the target operating systems for a java support such a mechanism. Do you have some proof that they do?

Comment: Thanks. I don't, and I realize OS portability may indeed be the problem stopping Java from being able to provide that ability - see my earlier comment above on my question. I am just trying to find out if any other library has been able to solve the problem creatively.